# Mac Nginx. Can't change the default page

Tags: macos, nginx, settings, default

I sadly can't get my nginx default page settings to work. I have already deleted all the preinstalled html files in /var/www/, but it still gets to load the default one.. (Also cleared the browser cache)

My current files:

nginx.conf

```
    worker_processes  1;

error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include             mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;

keepalive_timeout   65;

index index.html index.php;

include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; 
}
```

sites-available/default

```
    server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
root       /var/www/;

access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.access.log  main;

location / {
    include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
}

error_page  404     /404.html;
error_page  403     /403.html;
}
```

sites-enabled contains aliases of the files in sites-available.

Hope I didn't miss anything there!

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: Considering that you're throwing everything to php-fpm, what page is being shown? 
(I'm wondering if PHP-FPM is pulling a default file from somewhere.)

Comment: @kyl191 I've worked with the following guide. http://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/ how could I figure out where this default page gets pulled from? I already placed all my php files into the /var/www/ Any solutions? thanks

Comment: What is this default page though? Could you link to a screenshot of it? And do the access & error log say anything?

Comment: Offhand, the only thing I can think of is that you should try adding `try_files $uri =404` below the `include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;` directive, and see if you can get to any static resource/page. (ie, just put any file in /var/www, see if you can get to it with localhost/file.ext)

Comment: @kyl191 Here is a screenshot of my current default page: http://imgur.com/rGYPtuW it's set by the tutorial linked above. When forcing a 404 the error log says 2015/04/23 22:12:12 [error] 850#0: *4 open() "/var/www404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost" (why does it redirect to /var/www404 instead of /var/www/404.php - NOTE: I changed the file type to PHP from html). When inserting the try_files I get an connection error even on existing files!After nginx start(error log): http://imgur.com/lvt4mgn

Comment: @OneStepCloser, did you manage to solve the problem? I'm facing the same issue here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... let's try this:

In `usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, replace the entire `location /` block with

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This tells nginx to first look for the named file, then the directory with the name, then finally pass it onto index.php. (To learn more about how nginx does location block matching, I suggest [this Digital Ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks).)

Then, in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm`, delete the `try_files      $uri = 404;` line.

I'm pretty sure it's the line causing the `/var/www404` lookup because there's not supposed to be a space between `= 404`. Also, the try_files in the section doesn't do too much.

As for where it's pulling the content from, the 'Clone my example virtual host' step is copying index.html into `/var/www`.

Comment: Completed the steps, and also thanks for the article. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to solve the problem: Calling localhost still showes the default page and an url like localhost/index.php always throws an 500 Internal Server Error. The error log writes the following: [error] 617#0: *4 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost". Since it's pulling the default page from /var/www/index.html (already deleted),I don't understand how it is able to catch it anyways.

Comment: In that case, I would say wipe everything and retry the tutorial. The fact that the default page is weirdly persistent makes no sense. For what it's worth https://gist.github.com/kyl191/ac8a77ddc0791fc28c95 is my nginx config.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm gonna reinstall all those things and give it another try.